# Disabled <select> multiple and IE7

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7

I am trying to display a multiple select that is disabled and has some options selected. The following fragment works well on Chrome and FF, but I can't seem to see the selected items on IE7. Anyone know a way to make it work?

```
<select multiple="multiple" disabled="disabled">
 <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
 <option value="saab" selected="selected" style="color:white">Saab</option>
 <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
 <option value="audi" selected="selected" style="color:white">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE7 simply does not support the styling of disabled elements, SELECT especially.